# get Result only from one Collection mongodb/Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm

I wanted to select cities depending from countries so i made this code, but the funny things here is that code show me only the id of the countries that's it and he ignores totally the cities query, it doesn't return nothing:

```
public function ctsAction() {


                $ctry = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                       ->getRepository('indexBundle:Ctes')
                       ->findOneByCountryName($q_country);

                if( !empty($ctry) ) 
                {
                    $search_country = $ctry->getCtryId();

                    $cties_list = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                                   ->getRepository('indexBundle:Cties')
                                   ->findOneByCountryId($ctry);
                }



    }
```

If u need some other things tell me, from where comes the problem?

Comment: Is this normal 'indexBundle:Ctes' and 'indexBundle:Cties' ?

Comment: Your `$q_country` variable seems to be uninizialized

Comment: Actually i find somehow he problem, the problem is that i render the result wrong, i made $return =  array(); $return = $cities_list;, which doesn't show nothing , my question now is how can I set the result from $cities_list(only the cities name) to one array, bc when I try with findone it works good but I don't know how to make it with find

Comment: @Clement yes Ctes for countries and Cties for Cities Collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved like that:

```
$result =  array();
$return = array();
$result = $cties_list->toArray();
foreach ($result as $val) {
  array_push($return, $val->getCityName());
};
```

If there is any other suggestion, don't hesitate